# pandas groupby - return min() along with time where min() occurs

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, min

My data is organized in multi-index dataframes. I am trying to groupby the "Sweep" index and return both the min (or max) in a specific time range, along with the time at which that time occurs.

Data looks like:

```
             Time       Primary  Secondary    BL LED
Sweep                                               
Sweep1 0  0.00000 -28173.828125  -0.416565 -0.000305
       1  0.00005 -27050.781250  -0.416260  0.000305
       2  0.00010 -27490.234375  -0.415955 -0.002441
       3  0.00015 -28222.656250  -0.416260  0.000305
       4  0.00020 -28759.765625  -0.414429 -0.002136
```

Getting the min or max is very straightforward.

```
def find_groupby_peak(voltage_df, start_time, end_time, peak="min"):
    boolean_vr = (voltage_df.Time >= start_time) & (voltage_df.Time <=end_time)
    df_subset = voltage_df[boolean_vr]
    grouped = df_subset.groupby(level="Sweep")
    if peak == "min":
        peak = grouped.Primary.min()
    elif peak == "max":
        peak = grouped.max()

    return peak
```

Which gives (partial output):

```
Sweep
Sweep1    -92333.984375
Sweep10   -86523.437500
Sweep11   -85205.078125
Sweep12   -87109.375000
Sweep13   -77929.687500
```

But I need to time where those peaks occur as well. I know I could iterate over the output and find where in the original dataset those values occur, but that seems like a rather brute-force way to do it. I also could write a different function to apply to the grouped object that returns both the max and the time where that max occurs (at least in theory - haven't tried to do this, but I assume it's pretty straightforward).

Other than those two options, is there a simpler way to pass the outputs from grouped.Primary.min() (i.e. the peak values) to return where in Time those values occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using the transform function with groupby. If you had data that look a bit like this:

```
import pandas as pd
sweep =     ["sweep1", "sweep1", "sweep1", "sweep1", 
            "sweep2", "sweep2", "sweep2", "sweep2",
            "sweep3", "sweep3", "sweep3", "sweep3",
            "sweep4", "sweep4", "sweep4", "sweep4"]
Time =      [0.009845, 0.002186,  0.006001,  0.00265,  
            0.003832,  0.005627,  0.002625,  0.004159,  
            0.00388,  0.008107,  0.00813,  0.004813, 
            0.003205,  0.003225,  0.00413,  0.001202]
Primary =   [-2832.013203,  -2478.839133,  -2100.671551,  -2057.188346,  
             -2605.402055,  -2030.195497,  -2300.209967,  -2504.817095,  
             -2865.320903,  -2456.0049,  -2542.132906,  -2405.657053,  
             -2780.140743,  -2351.743053,  -2232.340363,  -2820.27356]
s_count =   [ 0, 1, 2, 3,
              0, 1, 2, 3,
              0, 1, 2, 3,
              0, 1, 2, 3]

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Time'      : Time,
                    'Primary'   : Primary}, index = [sweep, s_count])
```

Then you could write a very simple transform function that will return for each group of data (grouped by the sweep index), the row at which the minimum value of 'Primary' is located. This you would do with simple boolean slicing. That would look like this:

```
def trans_function(df):
    return df[df.Primary == min(df.Primary)]
```

Then to use this function simply call it inside the `transform` method:

```
df.groupby(level = 0).transform(trans_function)
```

And that gives me the following output:

```
              Primary      Time
sweep1 0 -2832.013203  0.009845
sweep2 0 -2605.402055  0.003832
sweep3 0 -2865.320903  0.003880
sweep4 3 -2820.273560  0.001202
```

Obviously you could incorporate that into you function that is acting on some subset of the data if that is what you require.

As an alternative you could index the group by using the `argmin()` function. I tried to do this with transform but it was just returning the entire dataframe. I'm not sure why that should be, it does however work with `apply`:

```
def trans_function2(df):
    return df.loc[df['Primary'].argmin()]

df.groupby(level = 0).apply(trans_function2)
```

That again gives me:

```
            Primary      Time
sweep1 -2832.013203  0.009845
sweep2 -2605.402055  0.003832
sweep3 -2865.320903  0.003880
sweep4 -2820.273560  0.001202
```

I'm not totally sure why this function does not work with `transform` - perhaps someone will enlighten us.

Comment: your first solution (the trans_function + transform) works perfectly. Will have to read about groupby transform some more to understand what's going on there. thanks!

Comment: In my opinion the `transform` and `apply` functions are very opaque and the docs are not a great help. They are however extremely useful once you get to grips with them.

Comment: yeah just quickly reading through the docs on transform I'm still a bit confused. Just starting out though, so I've become accustomed to being a perpetual state of mild confusion ;)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this will work with your multi-index frame, but it is worth a try; working with:

```
>>> df
  tag       tick  val
z   C 2014-09-07   32
y   C 2014-09-08   67
x   A 2014-09-09   49
w   A 2014-09-10   80
v   B 2014-09-11   51
u   B 2014-09-12   25
t   C 2014-09-13   22
s   B 2014-09-14    8
r   A 2014-09-15   76
q   C 2014-09-16    4
```

find the indexer using `idxmax` and then use `.loc`:

```
>>> i = df.groupby('tag')['val'].idxmax()
>>> df.loc[i]
  tag       tick  val
w   A 2014-09-10   80
v   B 2014-09-11   51
y   C 2014-09-08   67
```